# shiro with jdbc and hashed passwords

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, hash, shiro

Here is my shiro config

```
[main]
authc.loginUrl = /site/index.jsp
authc.usernameParam = user
authc.passwordParam = pass
authc.rememberMeParam = remember
authc.successUrl = /site/home.jsp


jdbcRealm=org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled=true
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = select password from users where username = ?
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = select role from users where username = ?

credentialsMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.HashedCredentialsMatcher
credentialsMatcher.hashAlgorithmName = SHA-256
credentialsMatcher.storedCredentialsHexEncoded = true
credentialsMatcher.hashIterations = 5000
jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $credentialsMatcher



jof = org.apache.shiro.jndi.JndiObjectFactory
jof.resourceName = jdbc/postgres
jof.requiredType = javax.sql.DataSource
jof.resourceRef = true
jdbcRealm.dataSource = $jof
securityManager.realms = jdbcRealm

[urls]
/theme/** = anon
/site/** = authc
/site/cards.jsp = roles[smoto,admin]
/site/jobs.jsp = roles[admin]
```

I created the hash like this for admin password admin

```
String hashedPassword = new Sha256Hash("admin", "",5000).toHex();
```

I inserted the hash into the db but my authentication fails every time, does anyone have any experience with this kind of setup with shiro? Also how would I enable debugging or logging for shiro?

EDIT:
here is the correct set up for this kind of authentication, found it in another stackoverflow post

```
[main]
authc.loginUrl = /site/index.jsp
authc.usernameParam = user
authc.passwordParam = pass
authc.rememberMeParam = remember
authc.successUrl = /site/home.jsp

jdbcRealm=org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled=false
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = select password from users where username = ?
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = select role from users where username = ?

ps = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.DefaultPasswordService
pm = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.PasswordMatcher
pm.passwordService = $ps

jof = org.apache.shiro.jndi.JndiObjectFactory
jof.resourceName = jdbc/postgres
jof.requiredType = javax.sql.DataSource
jof.resourceRef = true

jdbcRealm.dataSource = $jof
jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $pm

#securityManager.realms = jdbcRealm

[urls]
/theme/** = anon
/site/** = authc
/site/cards.jsp = roles[smoto,admin]
/site/jobs.jsp = roles[admin]
```

The trick is to use the hashing tool that shiro provides and copy the exact output into database field "password", the whole string will contain info on what algorithm is used how many iteration etc, example:

```
$shiro1$SHA-256$500000$salthere$hashhere
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the HashedCredentialsMatcher, while sufficient, is a bit older.  You'll probably find Shiro's newer [PasswordMatcher](http://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.2/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/authc/credential/PasswordMatcher.html) easier to use.  You can configure its internal [PasswordService](http://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.2/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/authc/credential/PasswordService.html) pretty easily:

```
[main]
passwordService = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.DefaultPasswordService
#configure the passwordService to use the settings you desire
#...
passwordMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.PasswordMatcher
passwordMatcher.passwordService = $passwordService
#...
# Finally, set the matcher on a realm that requires password matching for account authentication:
myRealm = ...
myRealm.credentialsMatcher = $passwordMatcher
```

You can use an instance of the `PasswordService` in your application to create the password hash when you create an account or update the account's password:

```
String submittedPlaintextPassword = ...
String encryptedValue = passwordService.encryptPassword(submittedPlaintextPassword);
...
userAccount.setPassword(encryptedValue);
userAccount.save(); //create or update to your data store
```

Just make sure the passwordService configured in `shiro.ini` has the same configuration as the `passwordService` used in your application code.

Comment: Is there any way to log the passed password to shiro.ini? My app always returns, that my passed password is wrong ... I use a bit more complex hashing ... The password in my db looks like: $shiro1$SHA-256$1028$8Q4AlwW/3NloawqM4ijdQQ==$DWE96wyrASHjA/vKCDFtSanDrw44L3wF1/DXPrJrtio=